# jQuery event not firing on after DOM element is overwritten

Tags: jquery, mouseenter

First I am dynamically writing a table to a div using innerHTML and then I'm trying to get a jQuery function to run when a user hovers a table cell. The jQuery function fires on a table that exists in the HTML, but once I overwrite the innerHTML with a new table, jQuery doesn't run the function on hover anymore.

```
<div id="replaceThis">
    <table id="myTable">
        <tr><td class="myCell">Help</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Then I use .on('mousenter') to run a function

```
$('#myTable tr td.myCell').on('mouseenter',function(){alert('omg help'); }
```

This all works fine until I replace the innerHTML of the div with a new table, much bigger, that is created with a loop through some data. The jQuery then does not fire the function on the mouseenter even though the id's and classes are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use delegated events. When you replace the body, it generates new HTML elements, which do not have your event handler attached anymore.

jQuery provides the delegated handler feature with the `selector` parameter on the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function.

For instance:

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '#myTable tr td.myCell', function(){alert('omg help'); }
```

Read the *Direct and Delegated Events* paragraph in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thank you very much. The function is running on the innerHTML now.

Answer (score 1):

After the DOM element is overwritten the events are no longer attached to the DOM element. Using Delegated events will solve your problem.

<s>`$('#myTable tr td.myCell').on('mouseenter',function(){alert('omg help'); }`</s>

```
$('#replaceThis').on('mouseenter', "#myTable tr td.myCell", function () {
    alert('omg help');
});
```